# Accessing the properties of the last object in an array of objects?

Tags: php, arrays, oop

Given that you have an array that contains varying amounts of objects, how can you access the properties of the last object? I tried to use `end($array);` but it gives the error: `Object of class Post could not be converted to string`

The class is:

```
class Post {
        private $datafile;
        public $index;
        public $subIndex;
        public $poster;
        public $title;
        public $message;
        public $date;

// constructor and some unrelated methods here

        public function getCommentData($givenIndex) {
            $comments = null;
            $data = file($this->datafile);
            foreach($data as $row) {
                list($index, $subIndex, $poster, $message, $date) = explode('|', $row);
                $this->index = $subIndex; // SubIndex ties a Comment to a Post (same ID)
                if($this->index == $givenIndex) {
                    $comment = new Post();
                    $comment->poster = $poster;
                    $comment->message = $message;
                    $comment->date = date(DATEFORMAT, strtotime($date));
                    $comments[] = $comment;
                }
            }
            return $comments;
        }
}
```

Now, I would like to access only the last Comment item's properties, but I'm not sure how it should be done? In a regular array, end() is quick and easy to use, but how about with objects as it doesn't seem to work?

Here is an example var_dump:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => 
    object(Post)[4]
      private 'datafile' => null
      public 'index' => null
      public 'subIndex' => null
      public 'poster' => string 'Postaaja' (length=8)
      public 'title' => null
      public 'message' => string 'Kommentti' (length=9)
      public 'date' => string '5 Mar 2013 | 23:12' (length=18)
  1 => 
    object(Post)[5]
      private 'datafile' => null
      public 'index' => null
      public 'subIndex' => null
      public 'poster' => string 'Toinenkin' (length=9)
      public 'title' => null
      public 'message' => string 'Lisäkommentti' (length=14)
      public 'date' => string '5 Mar 2013 | 23:13' (length=18)
```

Thanks!

EDIT:
Here's the way I tried to use it:

```
$comments = new Post(FILECOMMENTS);
$currentComments = $comments->getCommentData($i); // $i is the index of current newspost item

$newsComments = new Format();
$newsComments->formatShortComment($currentComments, $i);
```

And the method in the Format class:

```
// This comment is displayed as a short text in the main News view
public function formatShortComment($data, $index) {?>
    <div class="newsComments">
        <p class="newsPreviewComment">
        <?php 
            $lastItem = end($data);
            if(!empty($lastItem->message)) {
                echo '<i>&quot;',$lastItem->message,'&quot;</i> ';
                echo '-',$lastItem->poster;
            }
        ?></p>
        &raquo; <a href="?page=comments&amp;id=<?php echo $index; ?>">Show All/Add comments</a>
        (<?php echo $commentCount; ?>)
    </div><?php
}
```

Comment: Please post the code that generates the error. Based on the description and what is shown here, it should work in theory, but can't say for sure without the code that's causing the issue.

Comment: How abt using array_pop($arrayofObjects);

Comment: @Adrian: I added the code to the post

Comment: Thanks for updating with the code - which line triggers the error mentioned in your original post?

Comment: @Adrian: the `$lastItem = end($data);` part triggers the error

Comment: @Cups: thanks! That did the trick :) now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
$tempArray = array_values($data);

$lastItem = $tempArray[count($tempArray)-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I didn't miss something important, but if you're just trying to get the last element of a PHP array:

```
$lastItem = $data[count($data) - 1];
```